# Finding asymptotes of a function using limits

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, asymptotics

I need to find asymptotes of a function. I didn't find any vertical asymptotes and I think there aren't any. But when trying to find a horizontal asymptote I evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches infinity but can't successfully find it.

$$f(x)=x\arctan(x)$$

Comment: That is because there is no horizontal asymptote, only an oblique (slant) one, $y = \frac{\pi}{2}|x|-1$

Comment: How would I find that oblique asymptote using limits?

Comment: How much do you know about Taylor series?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ has an oblique asymptote $y=a x + b$ when $x\to\infty$ iff

- $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = a$
- $\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-a x) = b$

Similar conditions hold for the case $x\to -\infty$.

For $f(x)= x \arctan(x)$ we have when $x\to +\infty$
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)}{x} = \arctan x\to \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}x = x(\arctan x - \frac{\pi}{2}) = - x \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \to -1
\end{equation}
Hence there is an oblique asymptote $y = \frac{\pi}{2} x - 1$ at $+\infty$.

What is the asymptote when $x\to -\infty$ ?